# Removing success message after jsp page refresh?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a JSP page which displays a success message on successful deletion of an item.

However, if the page is refreshed, I want the message to not be displayed. I tried all I could do but it just doesn't happen.

I am setting the attribute in a Struts 2 class in request scope. I am retrieving the same attribute in my JSP page using `request.getattribute()`. After the if statement, I am trying to set the same attribute to `null`. But the success message remains after refreshing the page which I don't want.

Please help!

Comment: Where is your code? Why don't you do it the S2 way?

Comment: You need to read about [MessageStore Interceptor and Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28542900/1654265). As it is now, you not only have the problem of the message shown twice, but also of the operation executed on every refresh, do you ?

Comment: when you are refreshing you are passing arguments through URL(assuming).please trim that before refreshing.

Comment: confidential. cant show it. sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh the page, (from the browser I assume)  you are  actually sending the same request to server again. Which means, it will execute whatever it executes, put again that attribute on request, and you will get it back in the JSP page.
If you want to avoid that, you should have a way to tell, on the server side, that the operation has been already executed in order not to put the attribute on the request( for example, if you insert something, always check before if is not inserted already, and if so, just don't put that attribute on the request).

Comment: Your suggestion worked! You genius! I put a counter in my jsp logic and allowed the message to be displayed only when the count is 0. If the message is displayed once, the counter increments and thus is not 0 so the mesage wont display. thanks!

Comment: glad to help. just mark the answer so that someone else will search for to know it can use the solution for a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: Very ugly way to solve that kind of problem with a counter.