# Form with field options loaded from DB and validation

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, interceptorstack

The situation is the following:

1. I have a JSP page with a form.
2. This form contains various `<select>` tags with options loaded from DB.
3. I want to use validation with an XML file.

The problem is the following: if I use an XML file and there are some errors in the form fields, the struts framework doesn't pass through the class method I laid out, but it will directly return the `input` result. So what's the point? That in this way I can't load the options for the various `<select>` tags I mentioned above.

So I thought to do something like this:

```xml
<result name="input" type="chain">
  <param name="actionName">Class_method</param>
</result>
```

but with this trick I lose all the error messages, i.e. `hasFieldErrors()` returns always false.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions, all good though.

1. [**Conversion** and **validation** errors forces the `Workflow` interceptor to trigger the `INPUT` result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265), and the workflow will execute the `INPUT` result *instead* of reaching the action method (`execute()` or whatever).
2. If you need to populate some static data, like selectboxes sources, that must be available also in case of `INPUT` result, you should put that loading in a `prepare()` method, and make your action implement the `Preparable` interface. This method is run by an Interceptor before the INPUT result is returned, [as described in the official docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html).
3. Avoid using the `chain` result. It is officially discouraged since many years.
4. If you want to prevent double submits (by pressing F5 after a page has been submitted and the result rendered), you can use the [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) with the `redirectAction` result. This way, however, you'd encounter the same problem of the `chain` result: the messages (and the parameters) will be lost.
5. To preserve the error messages, action errors and field errors across the redirections, you can use a predefined interceptor called `Message Store` Interceptor, that you must include in your stack because the `defaultStack` doesn't include it. I've described [how it works in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542900/1654265).
6. If you decide to use the Message Store along with PRG there are more considerations, too long to be written here, but that could be explained in the future, about preventing infinite recursion due to `Field Error -> INPUT -> PRG -> Retrieve Field Error -> INPUT -> etc...` that will be blocked by the browser near the 10th recursion... but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one thing, I tried and the Preparable interface *must* be implemented to let prepare interceptor call the prepare method.

Comment: You're right, `Preparable` is not natively implemented by `ActionSupport`, as I mis-remembered; I have `Preparable` implemented on my BaseAction that is extended by all the other actions... write once and forget :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
public class Foo extends ActionSupport {
    public string myAction() { return SUCCESS; }
    public void validateMyAction() { // executed after XML validation
        // other complex validation here if needed
        if (hasErrors()) {
            // repopulate form data from DB here
        }
    }
}
```

`hasErrors()` method comes from the `ValidationAware` interface which `ActionSupport` implements.

Another option is to do a redirect on `input` result and use the [message store interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/message-store-interceptor.html) to keep action messages